# Auto layout of multiple views

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, autolayout

I'm trying to use auto layout for positioning the following views inside a viewController that may have different sizes on different devices:

[image: Auto layout]

All of the UILabels should have fixed space from the top or bottom and between them.
The UIImageView should have flexible width and height according to the space that left, and a 1:1 aspect ratio.

The UILabels have the following constraints:

- Top space
- Bottom space
- Horizontal center in container

The UIImage view has the following constraints:

- Horizontal center in container
- 1:1 ratio
- Bottom space to label
- Top space to label
- Width: 100 (priority 250)
- Height: 100 (priority 250)

In the Xcode preview everything looks good, but when running the app the UIImage covers the entire screen instead of adjusting its width and height correctly.

Comment: is those views placed in the controller root view?

Comment: select one of your views on interface builder. then, click the triangular icon at the bottom right corner. at the bottom section that says All Views click on Update Frames. what is the results?

Comment: you also should remove the width and height constraint on the UIImageView for good

Comment: There are no misplaced views, so when I click "Update Frames" nothing happens.

Comment: I removed the width and height constraints and the problem still exists.

Comment: If you have the constraints as you described this should work.

Comment: do you have any code behind?

Comment: This viewController is a popover that is being created programmatically with different sizes on different devices.

Comment: But before the popover is being displayed, I call layoutIfNeeded() and updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

Comment: please add your code for  presenting the popover controller

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the label above `ImageView` is hooked to `Top space to Top Layout Guide` and bottom most label below `ImageView` is hooked to `Bottom space to bottom Layout Guide`.

Check whether all the labels below `ImageView` are hooked to the label under that.
Now check if the Image view is hooked to top and bottom labels. Give `width constraint` and get an outlet it.

As per the constraints Height of the `ImageView` varies according to screen height.
Width can be changed accordingly in program using width outlet as given below

```
self.img_width.constant = self.imgView.frame.size.height;
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin from every components.

Answer (score 0):

Just add Equal width constrain to image view with respect to Main View && give its multiplier to 0.5